# Google fetched a title from the body instead of keyword stuffed title tags - could that be a problem for SEO?

Tags: seo, keywords, search-results, title, keyword-stuffing

I have a website that contains keywords repeated in the `<title>` tag, so Google fetched the most relevant keywords from the body of the page.

There is no problem so far and my website is ranking 4th or 5th in SERP for my main keywords.

My question is: Will Google penalize my site or will it create a negative impact on Google since Google neglected my Meta title and fetched a title from the body instead?

**Note:**

I can modify my `<title>` tag, but my keyword ranking is good, and also my website has 10 years of domain age and I'm afraid that if I change its titles, the SERP position may get very impacted.

Comment: If it's questionable to you, why don't you just modify it?

Comment: If Google neglects your title, it's usually a sign that your title is less than optimal. Keyword stuffing can only harm you.

Comment: @dan I can modify, but keywords ranking is good only also my website is a old domain and i'm afraid that if i change those titles, SERP position may get very. so i'm afraid of changing the title tag. Pls give any suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will Google penalize my site or will it create a negative impact on Google...

Quite possibly.

As Google states [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66358?hl=en):

> **Keyword stuffing**
>
> "Keyword stuffing" refers to the practice of loading a webpage with
>   keywords or numbers in an attempt to manipulate a site's ranking in
>   Google search results. Often these keywords appear in a list or group,
>   or out of context (not as natural prose). Filling pages with keywords
>   or numbers results in a negative user experience, and can harm your
>   site's ranking. Focus on creating useful, information-rich content
>   that uses keywords appropriately and in context.

Google's [Penguin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Penguin) update specifically targets things like keyword stuffing, which can be construed as a [black hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spamdexing) technique.

Since Google disregarded your `<title>` tag, you should consider modifying it to conform with the [Quality Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en#3) contained in their [Webmaster Guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769?hl=en).

You should also be aware that just because Google didn't appear to penalize your site so far, complaints (possibly from competitors) might trigger that in the future.

A well-crafted title containing relevant keywords certainly shouldn't hurt your SERP if your content is already ranking highly.